# "hung in parchment folds"

Tags: meaning, sarah-relyea, playground-zero

> After a long climb, she emerged on a wooded hill, above a Greek-style amphitheater. She was surrounded by golden grasses, whose feathery seeds were borne on the wind. Eucalyptus fronds, giving off pungent odors, swayed in the languorous air rising from the bay. Crescents of dry foliage formed a treacherous ground cover. She climbed slowly, using roots and bare earth for footing. Approaching a eucalyptus tree, she fingered some bark that hung in parchment folds from the soaring trunk. (*Playground Zero* by Sarah Relyea)

Two places in this passage kind of elude me. "She was surrounded by golden grasses, whose feathery seeds were borne on the wind." The imagine invoked seems to be wind carrying feathery seeds and the woman surrounded by golden grasses that hold up the seeds in the wind. But since "bear" has tons of other meanings, I thought it could also be describing wind yielding seeds.

I also can't be sure what "she fingered some bark that hung in parchment folds from the soaring trunk" is portraying for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The grass seeds are feathery enough to be carried easily on the wind.**

The adjective "feathery" helps us to understand what kind of seeds are being talked about: it's not tough hard seeds like those of grapes, but something more like the seeds of dandelions, fluffy and light, carried by the wind for long distances as part of the plants' spreading strategy. Such seeds are most famously seen on dandelions, but also on various types of "golden grasses":

[image]
[image]

**Eucalyptus bark really does hang in folds like parchment.**

The tree being described at the end of the quoted passage is not just any tree but specifically a eucalyptus tree. These are very distinctive, especially in their colour and their bark, and they do indeed have a shape that could be described as "parchment folds":

[image]
[image]